# I was wondering what the {blogs: blogs}, mean in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

```
   app.get("/blogs", function(req, res){
   Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
       if(err){
           console.log("error!!!");
       }else{
           res.render("index", `{blogs: blogs}`);
       }
   });
```

This is my code from the web development bootcamp, from colt steele

Comment: Simple object literal with one own key: `blogs`. The key refers to `blogs` variable in that context.

Comment: Are the backticks around `{blogs: blogs}` **really** in your code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think he has wrapped the snippet with backticks just for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

**If** it's actually as you've shown it, it's just the literal text `{blogs: blogs}`. It's in an untagged template literal (so a string is created), and it's not in a token within that literal, so it's just text:

```js
console.log(`{blogs: blogs}`); // "{blogs: blogs}"
```

**But**, if it were:

```
res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
```

(without the backticks), then it would be an object initializer (often caled an "object literal") that creates an object with a single property of its own called `blogs` with the value from the `blogs` variable:

```js
const blogs = "value of blogs";
const obj = {blogs: blogs};
console.log(obj.blogs); // "value of blogs"
```

That initializer would create the object and pass it to `render` as the second argument.

In modern environments (ES2015+), you could write it with shorthand property notation: `{blogs}`.

Answer (score 1):

res.render("index", `{blogs: blogs}`);

This line will render the view template. Here *first blogs* refer to the name of the property, which will be used in template and *second blogs* refer to the response which we got from server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: JS keys in an object]

This is a simple graphical expression of JavaScript keys.(To make your concepts more clear.)

```
res.render("index", `{blogs: blogs}`);
```

You're using EJS, and this above-mentioned line of your code helps **'view engine'** or simply **EJS** to render or pop-up the key value "blogs" into your **index.ejs** dynamically (where you used **<%=blogs%>** in your **index.ejs**)

Hope it helped you clear your doubts.
Thank you.